# Exception Handling Ordering

Tags: java, exception

Why is the stack trace `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: 3`
and not `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: 1`? 
Isn't `ArithmeticException("1")` thrown first?

```
 try{
        try{
            throw new ArithmeticException("1");
        }finally{
            throw new ArithmeticException("2");
        }
    }finally{
        throw new ArithmeticException("3");
    }
```

Comment: Last thrown exception is from finally block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the `"1"` exception is thrown first. However:

Your `finally`s overwrite the exceptions thrown in the try blocks, so the `finally` exceptions are the only ones seen by the exception handling code.

Don't throw or return in a finally block, for precisely this reason.

See the description of this problem in [Google's Error Prone documentation](http://errorprone.info/bugpattern/Finally) for a lot more detail.

Comment: Nice and precise ... off-topic request: I put up this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47729575/is-there-a-way-of-gson-to-be-not-lenient-at-all) lately, and didn't see any feedback. I consider putting up a bounty - but before doing so: do you think the question is reasonable, or is there something I could improve?